# How to convert date in MYSQL to correct format

Tags: mysql

My current date formats are 01/01/2013 .... DD/MM/YYYY

How can I convert them all into MYSQL dates? I'm under The impression they are in the format YYYY-MM-DD

I don't know where to start.

my problem is that the dates are being ordered in the american way whilst they are in british format :(

Comment: There is a mysql manual that should help with such questions: [12.7 Date and Time Functions: STR_TO_DATE(str,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: my problem is that the dates are being ordered in the american way whilst they are in british format :(

Comment: In one comment you write `[...]I just imported data from a CSV and its being ordered wrong[...]`. You should rephrase your question. Where are the dates you want to convert, are they already in the database ? Or do you want to convert the dates while import? How do you import the CSV?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query.

```
update tbl_name set your_field_name= str_to_date(your_field_name, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

It will update the value of your date from DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY/MM/DD.

Then you can change your filed type to date.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract each part in php and concat the dd, mm, yyyy and save it to the DB

Comment: $var = '01/01/2013';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $var);
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

Comment: When suggesting to use php you should first find out if the OP uses php to communicate with mysql.

Comment: my problem is that the dates are being ordered in the american way whilst they are in british format :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not **[DATE_FORMAT](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/format-date-time-mysql/)**

```
DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Doesn't `DATE_FORMAT` expect `date` to be in the mysql format?

Comment: my problem is that the dates are being ordered in the american way whilst they are in british format :(

Answer (score 0):

**How to convert date in MYSQL to correct format:**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM tablename 

or

SELECT t.id,  DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(t.carddate, '%m/%d/%Y'), CURDATE)
FROM TABLE t
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_get-format

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: my problem is that the dates are being ordered in the american way whilst they are in british format :(

Comment: do you wants to convert the `timezone`.

Comment: i dont think so, I just imported data from a CSV and its being ordered wrong so I get 1st January, 1st February, instead of 1st January, 2nd February!

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar situation. I converted American date format "%Y-%d-%m" to correct format  '%Y-%m-%d'. This is how I did it...

```
    update table_name set my_date = DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( my_date, '%Y-%d-%m' ) , '%Y-%m-%d' );
```

The first date string format '%Y-%d-%m' needs to be how the date is currently formatted in your table. The second date string is what you want to convert it to.